# What is the best time of day to write? Day or night?

Tags: planning

What is the best time to write?

I write in the night, and am concerned for my health, because I'm missing the vitamin D of sunlight.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about health and not writing.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to Writers. As has been pointed out, this is likely a duplicate, but I will offer my opinion.

A lot of writing is done via *writer preference*. This means it's up to you what works and what doesn't. This doesn't stand for all of writing, of course. There are rules which other people have discovered and which, after thorough exploration, have been accepted as generally true. Still, a lot of what is 'right' or not is decided via writer preference.

When to write is one of those things. You should write whenever you feel you can turn out the best work. This goes for location as well. If you write best at night, then you should write at night.

Now if you're concerned about your vitamin D levels due to writing at night, that's an entirely separate issue. I am no doctor, but I would imagine low vitamin D levels would be easy to counter-act. Spend part of your day in the sun. Take a vitamin D supplement. If you are really concerned about it, ask your doctor. I'm sure he can point you in the right direction.

Best of luck with your endeavors!